# Does it matter if a drive extended in Disk Management (W10) looks like different partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

After installing a new HDD to be my primary storage drive, I deleted a couple of now redundant partitions on an old HDD and tried extending the data partition into those two partitions after each delete.

Each time, the extension seems to have worked, but it shows up looking like three partitions, but sharing a drive letter. Files on the drive seem to be fine to access and open.

Is this something that needs fixing? Or is it just a cosmetic thing in the Disk Manager and nothing to worry about?

[image: Data drive extended twice, now looks like three simple volumes rather than one.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dynamic disk. It's a special Windows-specific type of partitioning that is slightly more flexible, for example it allows to compose a partition of non-continuous disk parts. A Linux counterpart is called LVM.

It's not a problem per se, but it could make data recovery harder in case of some problems. But that's a moot point because you should have backups no matter what partitioning style you're using. Disks do fail now and then.